# A few questions about Stochastic Processes and Numerical Methods

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

I am having a few problems understanding the Ornstein Uhlenbeck solutions, on wikipedia under solution (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ornstein%E2%80%93Uhlenbeck_process) it described using variation of parameters with Ito's Lemma but I am struggling in getting df(x,t), I supposed I am also a little stuck in using Ito's lemma, as I am struggling with the definition I found on the wikipedia page.

It goes on to write an alternative form for the analytical solution without an integral, I am having troubles understanding how this equation was arrived at and how it differs from the other solution. Ideally I would look to simulate both solutions computationally afterwards so any advice would be greatly appreciated.

I would also like to get some help in understanding and arriving at, the errors associated with  numerical SDEs, for example Milstein and Euler-Maruyama.

Thank you for much for reading this I greatly appreciated it :)

Comment: I managed to figure out the first bit out about Ito's lemma and df(x,t) but any help with the other parts would be great!

Comment: As far as OH process resolution is concerned, this is just a variation of constant. Ito formula is without the stochastic correction, so it really looks like a normal ODE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the correct function $f$ is just guess-work. Sometimes it helps to treat the stochastic term as inhomogeneity and solve just the "homogenous" part, and then, as mookid said, use variation of constants. Sometimes, this does not work.

---

So in principle, one could have taken as reduced deterministic equation
$$
\dot x=θ(μ-x)\iff e^{θt}(\dot x+θx)=e^{θt}θμ\iff e^{θt}x=μe^{θt}+C
$$
to get the idea to explore the quantity $Y_t=(X_t-μ)e^{θt}$, $Y_0=X_0-μ$ and come up with
$$
dY_t=dX_te^{θt}+(X_t-μ)θe^{θt}\,dt=σe^{θt}\, dW_t
$$

---

How to get the exponential into the index: The increments 
$$
Δ W_t=W_{t+Δt}-W_t
$$
are random variables with a normal distribution $N(0,Δt)$. The scaled increments $e^{θt}Δ W_t$ are thus normally distributed with $N(0,e^{2θt}Δt)$. Let $\widetilde W_s$ be another Brownian motion, then 
$$
\widetilde W_{s+e^{2θt}Δt}-\widetilde W_s
$$
also has the distribution $N(0,e^{2θt}Δt)$. If we define the connection between $s$ and $t$ as a function $s_t$ with $Δs_t=e^{2θt}Δt$, or in the limit $Δt\to 0$ as $ds_t=e^{2θt}dt$, one gets $s_t=\frac1{2θ}e^{2θt}$. Then 
$$
e^{θt}\,d W_t\ \text{ and }\ d \widetilde W_{s_t}
$$
have always the same distribution, that is, 
$$
Y_0+σ\widetilde W_{s_t}\ \text{ and }\ Y_t=Y_0+\int_0^te^{θτ}\,d W_τ
$$ 
are equivalent (in distribution) processes.

---

In the same way that one gets factors into the time, one can also extract them, especially constant factors, so that 
$$
\tilde Y_t=Y_0+\frac{σ}{\sqrt{2θ}}\widetilde W_{\exp(2θt)}
$$
is another process equivalent to $Y_t$, and 
$$
\tilde X_t=μ+e^{-θt}\tilde Y_t=μ+e^{-θt}\left(X_0-μ+\frac{σ}{\sqrt{2θ}}\widetilde W_{e^{2θt}}\right)
$$
is a stochastic process that is equivalent (in distribution) to the solution $X_t$ of the Ornstein-Uhlenbeck equation
$$
dX_t = \theta (\mu-X_t)\,dt + \sigma\, dW_t.
$$